# yii2: use asInteger() and asDecimal() without thousands separator

Tags: yii2

how to use `Yii::$app->formatter->asInteger()` and `Yii::$app->formatter->asDecimal()` without thousands separator or with custom thousands separator (I don't want to make changes everywhere. Only in one particular place).

**EDITE:**

I found that `asInteger` function accepts two optional parameter [( yii2 API Documentation)](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter#asInteger()-detail): 
(`asInteger( $value, $options = [], $textOptions = [] )`). and I tried using theme this way:

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asInteger( 100000000,[NumberFormatter::GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL=>'*',NumberFormatter::MONETARY_GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL=>'*']);
```

but not working correctly. it will output `*۱۰۰۰۰۰۰۰۰` as result insted `۱۰۰*۰۰۰*۰۰۰`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as simple as add this chunk of code in to your config file:

```
'components' => [
        'formatter' => [
            'dateFormat' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
            'decimalSeparator' => ',',
            'thousandSeparator' => ' ',
            'currencyCode' => 'EUR',
       ],
    ],
```

And adjust them like you wish. Also you can look up for more configs at: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-formatting

Comment: this will set config hole the project.I don't want to make changes everywhere. Only in one particular place